# Why does account show 0 balance, after seemingly successful transaction in geth console?

Tags: transactions

It seems I've made a successful transaction from account[0] to account[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVfAL.png). Why does account[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVfAL.png) still have a 0 balance?

```
> var sender = eth.accounts[0];
undefined
> sender
"0x702543f4ae6d7ebdd07dc29c432a0c707b8c2cc0"
> var receiver = eth.accounts[1];
undefined
> receiver
"0xac97d0feb8b4b3bcaa2b153dff1d4eaa5b4bee9c"
> var amount = web3.toWei(1000, 'ether');
undefined
> eth.sendTransaction({from:sender, to:receiver, value: amount})
account is locked
    at web3.js:3119:20
    at web3.js:6023:15
    at web3.js:4995:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1

> personal.unlockAccount(sender, "valid_passphrase")
true
> personal.unlockAccount(receiver, "valid_passphase")
true

> eth.sendTransaction({from:sender, to:receiver, value: amount})
I0602 20:32:38.038644 eth/api.go:1193] Tx(0xa7c9e4af88ca93f8bd3c488ed0807da3ec5879456cce9a3093a690a3ccb1dba8) to: 0xac97d0feb8b4b3bcaa2b153dff1d4eaa5b4bee9c
"0xa7c9e4af88ca93f8bd3c488ed0807da3ec5879456cce9a3093a690a3ccb1dba8"


> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])
6.79703125e+21
> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[1])
0
```

`eth.getTransaction("0xa7c9e4af88ca93f8bd3c488ed0807da3ec5879456cce9a3093a690a3ccb1dba8")`

```
{
  blockHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  blockNumber: null,
  from: "0x702543f4ae6d7ebdd07dc29c432a0c707b8c2cc0",
  gas: 90000,
  gasPrice: 20000000000,
  hash: "0xa7c9e4af88ca93f8bd3c488ed0807da3ec5879456cce9a3093a690a3ccb1dba8",
  input: "0x",
  nonce: 0,
  to: "0xac97d0feb8b4b3bcaa2b153dff1d4eaa5b4bee9c",
  transactionIndex: null,
  value: 1e+21
}
```

SOLUTION:

`miner.start(8)`

Let the miner run for a couple minutes.

`miner.stop()`

`eth.getTransaction("0xa7c9e4af88ca93f8bd3c488ed0807da3ec5879456cce9a3093a690a3ccb1dba8")`

```
{
  blockHash: "0xea06bc12fc1db50416adc90ec0856946f3e69b6bba3ec6722ecaf04538184667",
  blockNumber: 1330,
  from: "0x702543f4ae6d7ebdd07dc29c432a0c707b8c2cc0",
  gas: 90000,
  gasPrice: 20000000000,
  hash: "0xa7c9e4af88ca93f8bd3c488ed0807da3ec5879456cce9a3093a690a3ccb1dba8",
  input: "0x",
  nonce: 0,
  to: "0xac97d0feb8b4b3bcaa2b153dff1d4eaa5b4bee9c",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  value: 1e+21
}
```

Comment: Can you try eth.getTransaction("0xa7c9e4af88ca93f8bd3c488ed0807da3ec5879456cce9a3093a690a3ccb1dba8") and confirm that the transaction was mined?

Comment: looks like it wasn't mined because the block number is null...

Comment: I made the transaction in the geth console, while the miner was stopped. If I start the miner, should it eventually mine this transaction?

Comment: It should if the transaction is still floating around in the transaction pool. If you shut down all your `geth` instances, the transaction will be lost.

Comment: probably a silly question, how can I run multiple nodes on a local chain?

Comment: ran the miner, and the transaction was mined! updated post to show results

Comment: Great. You might want to post your results as an answer and tick it off in 2 days. To find out how to run multiple nodes, search this site for "trusted-nodes.json", "static-nodes.json", "bootnode" and private network.

Answer (score 2):

`miner.start(8)`

Let the miner run for a couple minutes.

`miner.stop()`

`eth.getTransaction("0xa7c9e4af88ca93f8bd3c488ed0807da3ec5879456cce9a3093a690a3ccb1dba8")`

```
{
  blockHash: "0xea06bc12fc1db50416adc90ec0856946f3e69b6bba3ec6722ecaf04538184667",
  blockNumber: 1330,
  from: "0x702543f4ae6d7ebdd07dc29c432a0c707b8c2cc0",
  gas: 90000,
  gasPrice: 20000000000,
  hash: "0xa7c9e4af88ca93f8bd3c488ed0807da3ec5879456cce9a3093a690a3ccb1dba8",
  input: "0x",
  nonce: 0,
  to: "0xac97d0feb8b4b3bcaa2b153dff1d4eaa5b4bee9c",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  value: 1e+21
}
```